# My variable's value is 0, but I didn't set it to 0

Tags: zsh, variable

Today I noticed one of my zsh functions is not functioning; I investigated the issue, and the culprit was this:

```
for i in a b
do
echo "$i"
done
0
0
```

Then I opened a new zsh, and in that, things were working normally:

```
for i in a b
do
echo "$i"
done
a
b
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind the first one acting weird to me?

Comment: Was variable `i` previously typeset (or declared) as an integer in the first case?

Comment: @steeldriver I changed `i` to `weirdName13` and it indeed fixed the issue. But I hadn't done anything with i. How can one undo this typeset? And how can I protect my scripts when i is typeset as an integer?

Comment: @HappyFace if you haven't [declared your function's local variables](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Local-Parameters) as local, expect them to be stomped by random things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
% typeset -i i
% for i in a b; print $i
0
0
```

Variables in `zsh` can be assigned various types, above `-i` for "represent internally as an integer", which will cause the variable to be represented as that. This can also be done via `integer i`. There are various ways to inspect what a variable is:

```
% print ${(t)i}
integer
% typeset -p i
typeset -i i=0
```

And the usual shell `+` to disable (see also `set -x`, `set +x`) it:

```
% typeset +i i
% for i in a b; print $i
a
b
```

It may be beneficial to hunt down what changed the type of that variable and restrict that change to a local scope (within a function) so that the global namespace is not polluted with random types, especially on oft used throwaway variable names such as `i`. It is rather easy to pollute the global namespace, as all that requires is assignment to an undeclared variable:

```
% () { local l=42; g=43 }
% print $l

% print $g
43
```

Or someone could needlessly add the `-g` flag to a `typeset` which makes the variable global:

```
% () { typeset -g -i h=42 }
% for h in a b; print $h
0
0
```

Exported variables may persist into new processes (a non-subshell child via `fork`, or a replacement via `exec`), but not the type:

```
% export -i h=42
% print $h ${(t)h}
42 integer-export

% ( print ${(t)h} )
integer-export

% exec zsh -l
% print $h ${(t)h}
42 scalar-export
```

Comment: Is it possible to protect a script against this pollution?

Comment: "a script" runs as a different process, as I understand it, so should not be affected. if you are sourcing random code (`.`, `source`, `eval`) into an existing process then bad code could easily pollute the environment, in which case you'll either need to not do that, or audit every line of the random code to see what it does

Comment: I think you could also `unset var` to make it lose any special properties it may have. Well, unless it's also readonly, in which case you'd need to `typeset +r var` first. Bash and ksh could have the same issue with variables set as integers, with the same solution. Except that you can't `unset` readonly variables in them.

Comment: @ilkkachu, also, in bash or mksh, you may need to call `unset` several times in case it has been declared local in several ancestor contexts (in those (and `yash`, `unset` doesn't unset, it peels off one layer of `local` (except in `bash` when the variable has been declared in the _current_ context)).

Comment: What's _a non-subshell child via fork_? `export` is for scalar variables to be transmitted across execs, that's independent of processes.

Comment: subshell children get the type of the variable. non-subshell children do not

Comment: But what's a non-subshell child? Is that a child that has executed another command? Before it executes that command, it's still a _subshell_, a process still running the shell. What I'm saying is that it doesn't make sense to talk in terms of processes here. The boundary is the _execution_ of a command.